# Asp.net programmatically add HTML to page

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm creating a web page which gets records from a database, these records are mapped as dictionary. I want to be able to dynamically create a structure as follows

```
<ul>
<li>row.GetString("firstname")</li>
<li>row.GetStrin("lastname")</li>
</ul>
```

so far i have mapped the results and i am looping each record please can some one help me with how i may be able to dynamically create html using c#

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you may use `BulletedList` control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about an [ASP.NET repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

*PD: Check the sample in this MSDN article and you'll get instructed in how to use it.*

Answer (score 1):

First drop an asp label in the place where you want your list to appear.
This is assuming that you're looping through a datatable:

```
YourLabel.Text = "<ul>";
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
    YourLabel.Text += "<li>" + row["firstname"] + "</li>";
    YourLabel.Text += "<li>" + row["lastname"] + "</li>";
}
YourLabel.Text += "</ul>";
```